# Trouble with adding up cells in second column if the first ones are identical in double dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

My excel file looks something like this:

```
Work    Pairs  Name
strobel 400 Katarina
strobel 200 Katarina
strobel 200 Katarina
sekanie 400 Katarina
sekanie 300 Katarina
sekanie 300 Katarina
sekanie 300 Katarina
sekanie 200 Katarina
sekanie 100 Katarina
```

Basically it lists an operation of what a person has done (Work), number of pairs done in such operation (Pairs) and person's name (Name).

I have already put everything into array by looping twice:

```
        For j = 1 To strDataRange.Rows.Count
            For k = 1 To 3
                arr(j, k) = strDataRange(j, k)
            Next k
        Next j
```

strDataRange is Range of Cells(2,1) to Cells(lastrow,3). This array is working properly.

What I need to do is if the operations in first column have same name, add the number of pairs done in such operation together and make a new list (or array) with this information, ie. final result would be

```
strobel 800 Katarina
sekanie 1600 Katarina
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this (very inexperienced with programming), and I would rather not waste 20 hours by trying things that wouldn't work even if I did them correctly.

My idea would be something like:

```
    For m = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(m, 1) = arr(m + 1, 1) Then
           <make new array where the pairs of first 2 matches add up>
           <somehow make this new array iterate until there are no 2 identical matches>
    Next m
```

Thanks a lot, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do it in VBA?

**Create a PivotTable:**

- Add Work to ROWS
- Add Pairs to VALUES

and voilà!

**How to create a Pivot Table**

Go to Insert->PivotTable. Proceed as mentioned above in the PivotTable fields panel.

Read more here:
https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Overview-of-PivotTable-and-PivotChart-reports-00a5bf71-65cb-49f9-b321-85bb7b0b06c2

Comment: Well the whole file is in excel (this is one worksheet, same operation would be done for every worksheet) and I have already done a lot of other macros there which are related to this issue. TBH I have no idea what a "PivotTable" is ^_^.

Comment: I would still do it using a PivotTable. I updated the post above with more details. Try to use VBA as little as possible as it is more prone to errors and not all users will be able/will now how to use the macros.

Comment: Thanks  Jean-François ;).

Comment: I was already checking pivot tables on google meanwhile you responded... HOLY COW HOW COULD I LIVE WITHOUT THIS. The macros would be primarly used by me or by people with strict instructions... So I guess the next step is learning how to create pivot tables using macros (as there are like 2500 sheets of nearly identical files).

Comment: If this involves 2500 worksheets then indeed it might make sense to use macros. I had no idea it would involve so many. Still you can still do it easily using PivotTables. Just use the record macro option in the Developer ribbon on 1 worksheet then adapt the generate sourcecode for the remaining worksheets. Refreshing all Pivots is easy: "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll"

Comment: Thanks for all the help! You saved me quite a few hours =). I have actually never used record a macro option, so I will have a look into that too.

Comment: Not sure I agree with "Try to use VBA as little as possible as it is more prone to errors and not all users will be able/will now how to use the macros", but in this case, PivotTables are the way to go! Code will be critical for making 2500 of them...

Comment: Thanks again for all help. I have finished the macros for this work today, and basically the way I did it is that I made first sheet of the workbook manually (Ie. names of columns, pivot tables etc) and then made macro to copy it into next 2000 sheets while also changing the pivot table selection values. Next I did macro to input the values into specific sheets and to refresh the pivot tables (annoying that they dont refresh on their own). Now I have another problem, but I have already posted the question about it and hopefully after I solve that, the whole file will be ready to go.

Comment: Hi emihir0, no problem! Glad it helped!